# MPU9250 with ESP32 - Cannot read magnetometer

Tags: c, embedded, esp32, i2c

I'm trying to read data from MPU9250. Accelerometer and gyroscope readings are fine. But I can not read anything successfully from the magnetometer. Looked in the datasheet and everything looks to be in order regarding the setup.

ST1 magnetometer register also is not read. Every time `I2Cread` function is called for magnetometer, the debug prints `Serial.print("Wire available: "); Serial.println(Wire.available());` are printing 0 (as far I understood this means there aren't any available bytes to be read). Any advice or help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

#define MPU9250_ADDRESS 0x68
#define MAG_ADDRESS 0x0C

#define GYRO_FULL_SCALE_250_DPS 0x00
#define GYRO_FULL_SCALE_500_DPS 0x08
#define GYRO_FULL_SCALE_1000_DPS 0x10
#define GYRO_FULL_SCALE_2000_DPS 0x18

#define ACC_FULL_SCALE_2_G 0x00
#define ACC_FULL_SCALE_4_G 0x08
#define ACC_FULL_SCALE_8_G 0x10
#define ACC_FULL_SCALE_16_G 0x18

void I2Cread(uint8_t Address, uint8_t Register, uint8_t Nbytes, uint8_t* Data)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(Address);
  Wire.write(Register);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(Address, Nbytes);
  uint8_t index = 0;
  Serial.print("Wire available: ");
  Serial.println(Wire.available());

  while (Wire.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Data array data:");
    Data[index++] = Wire.read();
    Serial.print(index-1);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(Data[index-1]);
  }
}

void I2CwriteByte(uint8_t Address, uint8_t Register, uint8_t Data)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(Address);
  Wire.write(Register);
  Wire.write(Data);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  I2CwriteByte(MPU9250_ADDRESS, 28, ACC_FULL_SCALE_16_G);

  I2CwriteByte(MPU9250_ADDRESS, 27, GYRO_FULL_SCALE_2000_DPS);

  // enable mag sensor bypass
  I2CwriteByte(MPU9250_ADDRESS, 0x37, 0x22);

  I2CwriteByte(MAG_ADDRESS, 0x0A, 0x01);
  delay(20);
  //I2CwriteByte(MAG_ADDRESS, 0x0A, 0x00);
}

void loop()
{
  uint8_t Buf[14];
  I2Cread(MPU9250_ADDRESS, 0x3B, 14, Buf);

  int16_t ax = -(Buf[0] << 8 | Buf[1]);
  int16_t ay = -(Buf[2] << 8 | Buf[3]);
  int16_t az = Buf[4] << 8 | Buf[5];

  int16_t gx = -(Buf[8] << 8 | Buf[9]);
  int16_t gy = -(Buf[10] << 8 | Buf[11]);
  int16_t gz = Buf[12] << 8 | Buf[13];

  uint8_t ST1;
  //I2CwriteByte(MAG_ADDRESS, 0x0A, 0x01);
  delay(20);
  do
  {
    I2Cread(MAG_ADDRESS, 0x02, 1, &ST1); // not read, 0 bytes available in read
    Serial.print("ST1: "); 
    Serial.println(ST1);
  } 
  while (!(ST1 & 0x01));

  uint8_t Mag[7];
  I2Cread(MAG_ADDRESS, 0x03, 7, Mag);
  //I2CwriteByte(MAG_ADDRESS, 0x0A, 0x00);
  Serial.println("Mag array data:");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(Mag[i]);
  }
  

  int16_t mx = -(Mag[3] << 8 | Mag[2]);
  int16_t my = -(Mag[1] << 8 | Mag[0]);
  int16_t mz = -(Mag[5] << 8 | Mag[4]);


  Serial.print(ax, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(ay, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(az, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(gx, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gy, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gz, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(mx + 200, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(my - 70, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(mz - 700, DEC);
  Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.println("");

  delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the block diagram at page 21 of [MPU9250 datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf), the compass ADCs are connected through an auxiliary i2c bus and configure via a bypass mux. In order to read the compass data, you need to config the [registers](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-9250-Register-Map.pdf) (register 37 and maybe others) to enable the bypass mode so that the data can be access at the main i2c bus connecting to the host.

If you can't figure out how to make it to work, take a look at a well-developed MPU9050 library to see how they do it, or simply use a readily-developed library.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed answer.

Turned out the chip was not MPU9250. It was MPU6050, which has the gyroscope and accelerometer but is missing the magnetometer entirely.

I made that conclusion after reading the WHOAMI register. For the sensor to be MPU9250, the register has to store the value 0x73, but I think it was 0x70. I am not sure entirely for the exact number but it was not the desired 0x73. I checked 0x70 value was a sign for MPU6050.

The funny part is that I bought it for a MPU9250. After short research it turned out I am not the only person in the world with that same problem. Hope no one else encounters the same thing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).